# To show error messages below fields for dynamically added rows

Tags: jquery, validation

Here is my validation code:

```js
$("tr.dynamicRow").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).find(".name").val();
  var b = $(this).find(".id").val();
  var c = $(this).find(".item").val();
  var d = $(this).find(".value").val();
  var e = $(this).find(".status").val();
  
  if (a === "") {
    valid = false;
    $(this).find(".name").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please select name</div>");
  }
  
  if (b === "") {
    valid = false;
    $(this).find(".id").after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please select id</div>");
  }
  
  if (c === "") {
    valid = false;
    $(this).find(".item").after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please select item</div>");
  }
  
  if (d === "") {
    valid = false;
    $(this).find(".value").after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please select value</div>");
  }
  
  if (e === "") {
    valid = false;
    $(this).find(".status").after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please select Status</div>");
  }
});
```

Result : Messages are displayed next to the text box.
Requirement : Messages to be displayed below the field.(JQuery/Javascript to be used)

Kindly help.

Comment: If your `div` elements are being displayed inline then this is a CSS issue, not a JS one. Also note that this code needs to be DRY'd up. It can be shortened significantly

Comment: Can you please tell me how to correct it?

Comment: Not really, as you've not included the CSS in the question

Comment: Here is my CSS code :                                                                                  .validation
{
   color: red;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}